# Error establishing connection: Unknown TDS packet type: 18 Any idea what is causing this? ODBC drivers?

Tags: sql, blackboard

Upgrading Blackboard 7.1 from SQL 2000 to SQL 2005 getting Error establishing connection: Unknown TDS packet type: 18 Any idea what is causing this? ODBC drivers?

Was on SQL 2000 and migrated the files to SQL 2005 instance.

I changed the connection strings within the object properties file for Blackboard and now getting this odd error.

Answer (score 2):

Verify your connection from osql at the command line.  It is also possible that you need to use a later Blackboard version than 7.1 as an updated JDBC driver may be required.